# :host selector isn't transformed into component entity when using webpack in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, pseudo-class

So first of all I run angular with webpack configured https://angular.io/guide/webpack#configuring-webpack and have a webpack sass-loader configured. It works fine except one thing I encountered today:

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ng-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './app.component.scss'
    ]
})
```

*app.component.scss*

```
:host {
    background: #f99d1c;
}
```

*The output html is:*

```
<style type="text/css">
:host { // but should be [_nghost-c0]
  background: #f99d1c; 
}
</style>
```

**The problem:**
Webpack sass plugin transpiles scss to css but not transforms :host,:host-context pseudo-selectors into component entities.

I didn't find any webpack plugins but investigated what it handles shadow compiler
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/shadow_css.ts
And I suppose angular-cli uses this compiler.

**The question:**
Any ideas how to work with angular webpack styles as it angular-cli does?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

*webpack.config.js*

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'to-string-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'css-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
            }]
        }
```

**FIX:**

After using `ng eject` on seed project I got webpack rule below and it works as expected (`[_nghost-c1]` instead of `:host` in output css)

```
        {
            'test': /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
            'use': [
                'exports-loader?module.exports.toString()',
                {
                    'loader': 'css-loader',
                    'options': {
                        'sourceMap': false,
                        'importLoaders': 1
                    }
                }, {
                    'loader': 'postcss-loader',
                    'options': {
                        'ident': 'postcss'
                    }
                }, {
                    'loader': 'sass-loader',
                    'options': {
                        'sourceMap': false,
                        'precision': 8,
                        'includePaths': []
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Which `loaders` do you have for the `.scss` files in your webpack configuration?

Comment: Could you add webpack configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting up your own webpack you can use the `ng eject` function to eject the webpack file. That will work well.

BTW you can go through that file and see what it differs from yours.

Comment: Thanks for help, didn't know about `ng reject` before. I've updated question. As I understand exports-loader converts `:host` to `[_nghost-c1]`

Answer (score 1):

Well you could actually replace all the :host CSS selectors with the names of their component. so instead of **`:host {}`** you can have **`my-component {}`**.

Give it a try

Comment: I can't.This is another component from common codebase.

Comment: Hmm ok then. I can't come up with any solutions right now. At least a soluction that i know of.